# Multiple where condition in a sql update statement with jinja template

Tags: python, sql, jinja2

I'm not very proficient with jinja but i'm trying to use jinjasql (https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql) in order to write a template for sql query in python.

Specifically I have an update query like this:

```
UPDATE {{schema_name | sqlsafe}}.{{table_name | sqlsafe}}
SET {{fields_update | sqlsafe}}= :update_value
WHERE {{fields_id | sqlsafe}}= :id_value
```

The values are taken from a yml configuration file.
`fields_id` is a list of column names of a particular table whose number can vary from table to table.

I'd like to have more than one condition in WHERE: Something like:

```
WHERE {{fields_id_1 | sqlsafe}}= :id_value_1 AND {{fields_id_2 | sqlsafe}}= :id_value_2
```

How to achieve that? Using for loop?

Comment: It can be done through Jinja macros. let me know how you will provide values ? is it in a list like field_id ?

Comment: yes it is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: (not sure, as I have not tested with real example):

**SQL Template:**

```
{% from 'macro.sql' import macro_join_condition %}

UPDATE {{schema_name | sqlsafe}}.{{table_name | sqlsafe}}
SET {{fields_update | sqlsafe}}= :update_value
WHERE {{ macro_join_condition(params.fields)}}
```

**macro.sql:**

```
{% macro macro_join_condition(fields) %}
  {% set idx = 1 %}
  {% for field in fields %}
    {% if loop.first %}
      WHERE {{ field }} | sqlsafe = :id_value_{{ idx }}
    {% else %}
      AND {{ field }} | sqlsafe = :id_value_{{ idx }}
    {% endif %}
    {% set idx = idx + 1 %}     
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```